# How to align a label above a form widget QT

Tags: c++, qt

I'm working with a narrow form with a slider. By default the slider's label is to the left (rtl language.) I want to put the label above the slider. I assume I could create a text widget, add that as a separate row, but I'm not sure if I lose accessibility or other benefits of the QT row.

Also, maybe I can make the whole form follow the "label above widget" pattern. Just not sure where that might be.

Current layout code:

```
myForm->addRow(tr("My Label:"), m_thicknessSlider);
```

[image: Slider with label on side]

Weirdly, I accidentally did the following, which provides the layout I'm looking for, mostly. But this seems wrong?

```
    myForm->addRow(tr("My Label:"), m_thicknessSlider);
    myForm->addRow(m_thicknessSlider);
```

[image: Slider with label above]

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you just need to ask. I dug a little more in the docs and found this:

```
myForm->setRowWrapPolicy(QFormLayout::WrapAllRows);
```

This forces wrapping on all rows.
Alternately, I can `setRowWrapPolicy(QFormLayout::WrapLongRows);` and then set  a minimum width on the slider:

```
m_thicknessSlider->setMinimumWidth(100);
```